# woocommerce_email_attachments filter arguments

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, attachments, email

I’m trying to generate PDF attachment for new order emails in WooCommerce and this is what I found:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_email_attachments', 'attach_terms_conditions_pdf_to_email');
function attach_terms_conditions_pdf_to_email($attachments, $type, $object) {
    $your_pdf_path = get_template_directory() . '/file.pdf';
    $attachments[] = $your_pdf_path;
    return $attachments;
}
```

This works, but I need to dynamically generate PDFs based on order (should be in `$object->order`), however nothing but `$attachments` is passed to my callback function – `$type` and `$object` are always `null`. `func_get_args()` gives only empty `$attachments` array.

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question. What are you trying to solve? What  have you tried already? What outcome are you expecting that isn't happening?

Comment: The question was why am I not getting `$type` and `$object` in the callback function, but anyway I already got the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mild stab in the dark, you aren't telling `add_filter` your accepted argument count. It's an important element. It does require you to also be explicit about the priority too.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_attachments',
  'attach_terms_conditions_pdf_to_email', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Correct. The default value of $accepted_args is 1. So if called without it, the filter will only pass the first variable -- in this case $attachments.

Comment: Thanks a million! It works! It was in the original code and at some point I removed it because I thought it's not needed. I knew 3rd param was priority, but never knew you had to provide number of arguments as a 4th param to the `add_filter` function.